# Customize buttons with SweetAlerts 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, sweetalert2

I need to match the custom design that was given to me. I am currently using SweetAlerts 2 for all dialog boxes with confirm and cancel. I need the cancel button to have a white background and teal colored text and teal colored border. Also borders for both buttons need a radius of 25px.

I can not find any parameters in the documentation that will do these things. I also can not find any other resources only for accomplishing this.

```
  // Delete click
  handleDeleteClick = () => {
    // Warning alert before delete
    Swal({
      title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
      type: 'warning',
      reverseButtons: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#4DB6AC',
      cancelButtonColor: 'white',
      confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        // Delete task
        axios.delete(`/api/goals/tasks/${this.props.task.id}`)
          .then(this.handleDeleteClickSuccess)
          .catch(this.handleDeleteClickError);
      }
    });
  }
```

I need the cancel button to have a white background and teal colored text and teal colored border. Also borders for both buttons need a radius of 25px.

EDIT:

```
/* Material UI styling */
const styles = theme => ({
  heading: {
    backgroundColor: '#E3E3E3',
    border: '1px solid #cccccc',
  },
  buttonsRight: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it possible to inspect the button and change the style by overriding the  properties of a CSS class using another style

```
.swal-button--cancel {
  // your css
}
```

Comment: I am still quite new at this ... I have been changing styles with material ui (code added to original question)
How would I implement .swal-button--cancel?

Answer (score -1):

You can change just change the SASS variables in your project.

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/src/variables.scss

Comment: I am still quite new at this... I'm not sure what to do with this info. I do not have a sass file.

Comment: changing package files may help you once, however when the package needs to be updated, you will have to change it from scratch.